# Какова этимология слова  "ширяться"?

Tags: этимология

Попалось у Высоцкого:

> Кто-то раны лечил боевые,
> Кто-то так, обеспечил тылы...
> Эх вы парни мои **шировые**,
> Поскорее слезайте с иглы!

А какова этимология слова "ширяться" и производных?

Нашёл слово *ширять*, но оно означает ворошить, а не колоть.

Comment: Зафиксирую ссылку на документ, подтверждающий запрет на продажу инъекционных шприцев в СССР (до 1989 г.). http://docs.cntd.ru/document/901700204

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если обратиться к Далю, то все просто. "Ширять" имеет значения: "рыть", "копать", "ковырять", которые красочно иллюстрируют действия торчков со своими венами)))

Answer (score 0):

В СССР можно было купить (или достать) шприцы чехословацкого завода Chirana. Правильное произношение этого слова - "Хирана" (потому что корни названия немецкие, а в немецком (да и в чешском тоже) сочетание "ch" произносится как "х").
Однако среди "золотой молодёжи" того времени было немало тех, кто закончил школы с углублённым изучением французского языка, поэтому стало популярным и преобладающим произношение "Ширана" (т.к. во французском сочетание букв "ch" обычно произносится именно как "ш" - например, Charles - Шарль, Champagne - Шампань).
Отсюда и произошло слово - сначала "**ширан**уться", а затем и "ширяться".
Существует, однако, и другая гипотеза. Среди той же "золотой молодёжи" был высок процент и тех, кто закончил английские школы. По-английски "шприц" "syringe". Более-менее приближенное к оригиналу произношение - "сириндж" или даже "ширинж" (ударение на первом слоге). Вот и выходит, что от "ширинж" вполне могло произойти слово "ширяться".
Что же касается слова "баян" в значении "шприц", то высока вероятность, что корни тут лежат в названии другой фирмы, поставлявшей в СССР шприцы - Bayer ("Байер"). Здесь просто произошла подгонка уже существовавшего русского слова "баян" под новый смысл.

Answer (score -1):

Мало кто знает этимологию слова «ширяться». На самом деле это слово происходит от слова Ширяна — неправильного произношения названия компании CHIRIANA (правильно Хирана), известного бренда медицинской техники. В советское время продавались шприцы этой марки и пользовались спросом у наркоманов. Известно выражение «баяна-ширяна», а баяном, как известно, называли шприц. Может быть, кстати, неправильное произношение бренда с буквой «я» сформировалось под воздействием созвучия со словом «баян».
Вот откуда взялось слово «ширяться».

Comment: А можно на источник посмотреть? Мне, человеку прожившему при советской власти бОльшую часть жизни, совершенно незнакомы ни фирма эта, ни такое значение слова "баяна", ни даже то, что в СССР можно было свободно купить (импортные!) шприцы. Да, сейчас эта бояна-ширяна фигурирует в словарях воровской лексики, но исключительно современных, первоисточником этого толкования стал лично писатель Баян Ширянов - в миру Воробьев Кирилл Борисович. Других первоисточников не обнаружено.